# Covariance of state and control input in LQG

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

Considering the following control system

${\dot {\mathbf {x} }}(t)=A(t)\mathbf {x} (t)+B(t)\mathbf {u} (t)+\mathbf {v} (t), \\
{\displaystyle \mathbf {y} (t)=C(t)\mathbf {x} (t)+\mathbf {w} (t),}$

where $\mathbf{x}$ is the state, $\mathbf{y}$ is the observation, $\mathbf{u}$ is the control input, $\mathbf{v}$ is the process disturbance and $\mathbf{w}$ is the obsevation noise.

The controller is given by

${\displaystyle {\dot {\hat {\mathbf {x} }}}(t)=A(t){\hat {\mathbf {x} }}(t)+B(t){\mathbf {u} }(t)+L(t)\left({\mathbf {y} }(t)-C(t){\hat {\mathbf {x} }}(t)\right)}\\
{\displaystyle {\mathbf {u} }(t)=-K(t){\hat {\mathbf {x} }}(t).}$

When the control gain $K$ and innovation gain $L$ are given and assumed to be time-invariant, can I obtain the covariance of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{u}$ directly from the continuous-time model?

Comment: Given the input $u$ and the LTI filter $\dot{x}=Ax+Bu$, $y=Cx$, can you find the covariance of $u$ and $y$?

Comment: Wouldn't the covariance of $u(t)$ be zero, since $\hat{x}(t)$ is known ($\mathbb{E}(\hat{x}(t))=\hat{x}(t)$) and thus $u(t)-\mathbb{E}(u(t))=K(t)\,(\mathbb{E}(\hat{x}(t))-\hat{x}(t))=0$?

Comment: @Arastas I know how to get the covariance when the system is in discrete-time form. But I do not know how to deal with it in the continuous-time case.